# Que ruta debo insertar para recoger el json de window.location.assign("/path/" + mijson) en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps

[image: mapa puntos centros comerciales]

Tengo un mapa con los centros comerciales, y una lista donde se muestran los datos id y nombre. Cuando se hace click en la lista se envía a una ruta.
En el código se ve como paso un json por url con el

> window.location.assign

, mi problema es que no sé en el archivo routes/web.php como recoger esa ruta para que llegue el JSON a mi controlador.

```
// Creamos el servicio PlaceService y enviamos la petición.
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.nearbySearch(request, function (results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      crearMarcador(results[i]);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      //console.log(results[i]);
      li.id = i;
      mijson = JSON.stringify([results[i]]);

      console.log(JSON.stringify([results[i]]));
      //mostrar rutas cuando selecionas un lil
      li.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
       window.location.assign("/path/" + mijson);
       //window.location.assign("/path/" + e.target.id);
      });

      li.innerHTML = results[i].name;
      li.innerHTML += "<br>" + results[i].vicinity;

      document.getElementById("lugares").appendChild(li);
    }
  }
});
```

La ruta de los links con console.log(results[i]), se visualiza así en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías mostrar como te queda la url de los links? si haces un console.log de "/path/" + mijson

Comment: He añadido  la información que me pides a la edición.

Comment: No creo que funcione la url así como está. Depende de lo que quieras que pase cuando el usuario clickee el link, podrías explicar más eso?. Por ej, si quieres que esa info se guarde en el servidor, creo que sería mejor enviar el json como data en una petición post, así en laravel tendrías una ruta post que lleve a una función del controlador y ahí tomas la data del Request.